# Compile C++ and OpenSSL on Ubuntu (Linux Mint 20)

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, openssl, linker

I'm about to compile a small C++ project with OpenSSL on Ubuntu (Linux Mint 20.1).

1. OpenSSL is installed regularly

   ```
   apt-get install libssl-dev
   ```
2. Compile line is

   ```
   g++ -std=c++11 -o jjp jjp.cpp -ljsoncpp -lssl
   ```
3. Compiler error output is

   ```
   jjp.cpp:(.text+0xe9d): undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_type_new'
   /usr/bin/ld: json3d.cpp:(.text+0xf0d): undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_set'
   /usr/bin/ld: jjp.cpp:(.text+0xf52): undefined reference to `BIO_new_fp'
   /usr/bin/ld: jjp.cpp:(.text+0xf7d): undefined reference to i2d_ASN1_OCTET_STRING'
   ```

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile and link **OpenSSL** library with success there are two mandatory flags in the compile line:

```
 "-lssl" and "-lcrypto"
```

So, correct compile line should be:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -o jjp jjp.cpp -ljsoncpp -lssl -lcrypto
```